# ASP.NET and SSAS

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, cube

I wrote a web-based program with ASP.NET. My data are in SQL SERVER and I use Cube to calculate several things. The question is as follow:
Is there anyway to connect ASP.NET app to Cube to handle everything automatically?
I said "automatically" cause I wrote this app via ASPx and it handles Cube Data fully automatic.
 A part of my old code

```
<dx:ASPxPivotGrid ID="ASPxPivotGrid1" runat="server" ClientIDMode="AutoID" Height="600px" 
    OLAPConnectionString="provider=MSOLAP;data source=localhost;initial catalog=MyCube;cube name="My Cube" >
          <Fields>
               <dx:PivotGridField ID="fieldYear1" AreaIndex="0" Caption="Year" FieldName="[Date].[Calendar].[Year]" GroupIndex="0" InnerGroupIndex="0" Visible="False">
```

**UPDATE:**
I know now how my question is stupid :)
Simple question: I use SQL Server 2012 among Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 and I want a cube browser for my web-based application. Is there any implementations? (Pfff this question is much better)

Comment: what do you mean by "handle" exactly? What behaviour are you wanting? What exactly happens "manually" at the moment which you'd like to happen "automatically" instead? It's not really clear.

Comment: Thank for asking @ADyson 
Yo know for retrieving data from cube yo need to "manually" write codes to feed a table in UI but in ASPx all you need is to connect to Cube and it does all the queries itself "automatically".